# Bioperl testing error in Perl

Tags: perl, bioperl

Newbie here, I am trying to use Bioperl module in the perl environment. My configuration are

- Windows Vista/32
- Active Perl 5.10.1
- Bioperl 1.6.1
- Padre and Per Studio 2010 IDE

For the installation guideline I went through [BioPerlWiki](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Installing_Bioperl_on_Windows) and used PPM method. I installed it successfully.

To check whether Bioperl was working I futher followed:

```
use Bio::Perl;  // Is working without error
```

But when I tried to do futher checking like

```
#!C:\Perl\bin
use Bio::Perl;
use strict;
$seq_object = get_sequence('swissprot',"ROA1_HUMAN");
write_sequence(">roa1.fasta",'fasta',$seq_object);
```

Then I am getting error

```
Global symbol "$seq_object" requires explicit packages name at c:\.......\example.pl line 4
Global symbol "$seq_object" requires explicit package name at c:\........\example.pl line 5
Execution of C:\...... \example.pl aborted due to compilation erros
```

I went to the `c:\perldoc Bio::Perl` and know it's uses, further more I tried to trace out errors through google too but dont know what's wrong.

I am aware of Perl and bioperl to be in system path too. Can anyone point me out what stupid mistakes I have been doing?

Will ask to bioperl mailing list too, but I know their reponse is not so fast like stackoverflow

Thank you

Comment: Aside from eugene's excellent answer, you should consider reading a couple of basic Perl tutorials on perldoc (as opposed to purely BioPerl module documentation) - it will save you a significant amount of time and aggravation. http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) pragma to extend the diagnostics emitted by Perl:

```
use diagnostics;
# your_code
```

This will provide you a verbose explanation:

> ```
> You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates
> that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my"),
> declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say
> which package the global variable is in (using "::").
> ```